# Extract some XML tags of a string with PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following function:

```
function translate($params) {
    $xmldata = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><root>' . html_entity_decode($params['data']) . '</root>';
    $lang = ucfirst(strtolower($params['lang']));
    if (simplexml_load_string($xmldata) === FALSE) {
        return $params['data'];
    } else {
        $langxmlobj = new SimpleXMLElement($xmldata);

        if ($langxmlobj -> $lang) {
            return ($langxmlobj -> $lang);
        } else {
            return $params['data'];
        }
    }
}
```

Which works great with strings like :

```
$params['data'] = '<English>Hello</English><French>Bonjour</French>';
$params['lang'] = 'English';
print translate($params);
```

it outputs :

```
Hello
```

But ...

When the string has any other tags in it :

```
$params['data'] = '<English><h1>Hello</h1></English><French><h1>Bonjour</h1></French>';
$params['lang'] = 'English';
```

It doesn't output anything;

I wanted it to output :

```
<h1>Hello</h1> or any other tag within the <LanguageQuotes>
```

Pulling my hairs out here; any idea ?

VERSION2:

It doesn't work when string is like:

```
$data = '<French><li><span class="pull-right">25 GB</span>Espace disque</French><English><li><span class="pull-right">25 GB</span>Disk Space</English>
<French><li><span class="pull-right">YES</span>PHP 5, MySQL 5</French><English><li><span class="pull-right">YES</span>PHP 5, MySQL 5</English>
<French><li><span class="pull-right">100</span>Bases de données</French><English><li><span class="pull-right">100</span>Databases</English>
<French><li><span class="pull-right">∞</span>E-Mails</French><English><li><span class="pull-right">∞</span>E-mails</English>';
```

Comment: Should not you keep your html string encoded inside XML?

Comment: On your version 2 `$data` the html is completely malformed, it has missing closing `</li>`'s

Comment: @akond no, it can be any structure, not necessarily Valid XML

Answer (score 3):

You're problem has two parts.

1. Load fragment with tags into a XML document
2. Fetch data from the XML

### Loading The Data Into XML

The main problem here is that it is not a valid XML fragment, but a mix of HTML fragments with some specific tags. Fortunately DOMDocument can load (and repair) HTML. This will not load the data as UTF-8 by default, you need to add the meta-tag specifying the encoding.

```
$data = '<French><li><span class="pull-right">25 GB</span>Espace disque</French><English><li><span class="pull-right">25 GB</span>Disk Space</English>
<French><li><span class="pull-right">YES</span>PHP 5, MySQL 5</French><English><li><span class="pull-right">YES</span>PHP 5, MySQL 5</English>
<French><li><span class="pull-right">100</span>Bases de données</French><English><li><span class="pull-right">100</span>Databases</English>
<French><li><span class="pull-right">∞</span>E-Mails</French><English><li><span class="pull-right">∞</span>E-mails</English>';    

$html_data = 
  '<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
   <body>'.$data.'</body>';

libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html_data);
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <body>
    <french>
      <li><span class="pull-right">25 GB</span>Espace disque</li>
    </french>
    <english>
      <li><span class="pull-right">25 GB</span>Disk Space</li>
    </english>
    <french>
      <li><span class="pull-right">YES</span>PHP 5, MySQL 5</li>
    </french>
    <english>
      <li><span class="pull-right">YES</span>PHP 5, MySQL 5</li>
    </english>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see that keeps the language name elements, but converts all names to lowercase. It always adds `html` and `body` elements if they are missing, but this is not a problem.

### Fetch Data From The XML

Now that you have a DOM you can use XPath to fetch nodes.

One possibility is to get the body element and import it to SimpleXML:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$root = simplexml_import_dom($xpath->evaluate('/html/body')->item(0));
var_dump($root);
```

Output:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2) {
  ["french"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
      ["li"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (1) {
        ["span"]=>
        string(5) "25 GB"
      }
    }
    ...
  }
  ["english"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
      ["li"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (1) {
        ["span"]=>
        string(5) "25 GB"
      }
    }
    ...
```

Or fetch the nodes directly and save them as HTML fragments:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$string = '';
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/html/body/*[name() = "english"]/*') as $node) {
  $string .= $dom->saveHtml($node);
}
echo $string;
```

Output:

```
<li>
<span class="pull-right">25 GB</span>Disk Space</li><li>
<span class="pull-right">YES</span>PHP 5, MySQL 5</li><li>
<span class="pull-right">100</span>Databases</li><li>
<span class="pull-right">∞</span>E-mails</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach might help you. I'm not enclosing data in XML, I don't think its needed here. You just need to find data between two custom tags.

```
/**
 * $matches[0] -> Returns string with the custom tag
 * $matches[1] -> Returns string without the custom tag
 * 
 * @param string $data
 * @param string $tag
 * @return string
 */
function find_between_custom_tag($data, $tag) {
    $regex = '/<' . $tag . '>(.*?)<\/' . $tag . '>/';
    preg_match($regex, $data, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

$data = '<English><h1>Hello</h1></English><French><h1>Bonjour</h1></French>';
$tag = 'English';

echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars( find_between_custom_tag($data, $tag) );
echo '</pre>';
```

**Outputs:**

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this could suit your purpose, but you could check for your tags using regex.

```
function extractXML($data,$ce) {
  $all = array(
    "en" => "english",
    "fr" => "french",
  );
  $lang = $all[$ce];
  if (!$lang) { $lang='english'; }
  $re = "/\<".$lang."?\>(.*?)\<\/".$lang."\>/i";
  preg_match_all($re,$data,$matches);
  foreach ($matches[1] as $name) {
    $return .= $name;
  }
  return $return;
}

//Load your XML data
$test = '
  <english>This is in english</english>
  <english><div><span>This is also in english</span></div></english>
  <french><div><span>This is some text</span></div></french>
  <french><span>Regex Power!</span></french>
';
$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><root></root>';
echo $str.extractXMLLang($test,'en');
```

This returns all the tags from within the languages properly. Just use `extractXMLLang(String,Language-Abbreviation)`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before by others: In Version 2 your XML is not valid, because you are using non-closing HTML inside of your XML-Tags.

If you want to keep HTML in XML, you will need to replace the special characters of the HTML code by its HTML entity. For this you can use the function `htmlspecialchars()`. You can also use `htmlentities()` as alternative. The latter one replaces more characters.

Replacing HTML entities by its character can be done with the function `html_entity_decode()`.

**Example:**

```
$htmlSpecialFrench = htmlspecialchars('<li><span class="pull-right">25 GB</span>Espace disque');
```

Then, the value of `$htmlSpecialFrench` is:

```
&lt;li&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;pull-right&quot;&gt;25 GB&lt;/span&gt;Espace disque
```

The same must be done for the English value, stored in `$htmlSpecialEnglish` for this example.

The transformed HTML can be included into the XML-Tags without interference to the XML-Syntax:

```
$data = "<French>$htmlSpecialFrench</French><English>$htmlSpecialEnglish</English>"
```

To get your original HTML from `$data` you first have to extract the value of the selected language with your function. Then you use `html_entity_decode()` to decode your transformed HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean, but perhaps these help:

Copy the script and paste into **designer** tab and get the script in **code** tab (use dreamweaver to handle this.
ex:

```
<?php
$params= '<English>&lt;h1&gt;Hello&lt;/h1&gt;</English><French>&lt;h1&gt;Bonjour&lt;/h1&gt;</French>';
print $params;
?>

&lt;h1&gt; for <h1>
&lt;/h1&gt; for</h1>
```